# Mercurial: How to undo all local changes that have not been pushed but have been committed

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have made a mess out of my local repo copy, but I don't really want to set the whole thing back up again. I just need to dump everything in hg out. All that is pushed up already is fine. Just not my local committed changes (some misguided backouts and merges).

Thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: if you use `SourceTree`, than here is option "Reverse Commit". It's create backout changeset(new commit with reversing changes). But, realy, i didn't try that.

Comment: I feel a little embarrassed now, but I just found the solution after I re-thought the question I put into Google. I would like to give someone points for the answer though.

Comment: can you give me that link, because i am also interested in solution, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/89064/how-do-i-remove-outgoing-changesets-in-mercurial-hg

Basically I just had to run: `hg strip 'roots(outgoing())'`
And the problem was solved.